# Uninstall package and its dependencies

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I'm trying to uninstall a private package, but because it is used by others packages Chocolatey show me this:

> Unable to uninstall 'tibco-businessworks 6.5.1' because 'bw_6.5.1_hf_002 6.5.1.002, tibco_bwpluginibmi 7.2.0' depend on it.

The problem is when I use this command

```
choco uninstall tibco-businessworks -forcedependencies
```

Chocolatey shows me the same message as before. I need it to uninstall leaf packages after that uninstall root package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chocolatey is trying to prevent other packages (and therefore their underlying applications) from no-longer working, by respecting the dependency chain that exists for the packages.

As per the [documentation](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-uninstall), the `--forcedependencies` option is used to:

> Uninstall dependencies when uninstalling package(s-). Defaults to false.

It does not have any impact on your current situation, since Chocolatey is telling your that other packages have a dependency on the package that you are trying to uninstall.

In order to remove the `tibco-businessworks` package, you will have to first remove the `bw_6.5.1_hf_002` and `tibco_bwpluginibmi` packages.

Comment: Yes, I see thank you, do you know how can I get leaf packages using powershell ?
from parent package need to know all leafs packages that have the parent package as a dependenciey
thank you